# how to pass the content of the TeX variable to Lua

Tags: luatex

How can I pass the content of the TeX variable `\jobname` to a Lua variable?

(I am using LuaLaTeX with the `luacode` package.)

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want: Mico's answer seems sensible, but that seems almost trivially-obvious so I wonder if there is more to the question.

Comment: Indeed, <code>\luadirect{p = \luastring{\jobname}}</code> does what I want. Many thanks to Mirco.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you're loading the `luacode` package, you could make use of its macro `\luastring`. (Yes, the name of the tex file in this example really is `uvw`.)

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function foo(s) -- "s" is a variable
  tex.sprint( s )
end
```

```lua
\end{luacode}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
The value of \verb+\jobname+ is \directlua{tex.sprint(\luastring{\jobname})}.

The value of \verb+\jobname+ is \texttt{\directlua{ foo(\luastring{\jobname})}}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see no Lua variable here.

Comment: @egreg - the macro `\luastring{...}` *creates* a Lua variable, which gets operated on by `tex.sprint` in the MWE. I've modified the MWE to set up a function that explicitly operates on a variable `s` that contains the value of `\luastring{\jobname}`.

Comment: Can one combine it with `dofile("...")` somehow?

Comment: @koppor - Sure can! (a) Plunk the three lines of Lua code into an external file called, say, `myfile.lua`. (b) Run `\directlua{dofile("myfile.lua")}` in the preamble. (c) Run `The value of \verb+\jobname+ is \texttt{\directlua{ foo(\luastring{\jobname})}}` as in the example shown above. If this instruction needs to be run several times, create a shortcut LaTeX macro, e.g., `\newcommand\printjobname{\texttt{\directlua{foo(\luastring{\jobname})}}}` in the preamble (and after running `dofile`); then, just type `The value of \verb+\jobname+ is \printjobname` in the body of the document. Cheers!

Comment: Thus there is an even number :-)

Answer (score 6):

An addition to Micos answer, you can also access the original `\jobname`, which was active at the start of LuaTeX: It is available as `tex.jobname`.
This will normally be the same as `\jobname`, except it doesn't change if `\jobname` is redefined:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
The value of \verb+\jobname+ is \directlua{tex.sprint(\luastring{\jobname})}, the ``real'' jobname is \directlua{tex.sprint(tex.jobname)}.

\renewcommand\jobname{somename}

The value of \verb+\jobname+ is \directlua{tex.sprint(\luastring{\jobname})}, the ``real'' jobname is \directlua{tex.sprint(tex.jobname)}.

% Change back, otherwise LaTeX is unhappy
\edef\jobname{\directlua{tex.sprint(tex.jobname)}}
\end{document}
```

If the jobname is job, this will result in
[image]