# Passing arguments to LuaLaTeX with LuaSQL

Tags: luatex, compiling, arguments

I am using LuaLaTeX with LuaSQL and I have two files which are `test.tex` and `test.lua`. When I compile with `lualatex test.tex`, first `test.lua` is ran and it reads user values from my database for rows where variable `id_user = 3`. This variable is set inside `test.lua`.

So currently every compilation returns values for same user, but I would like to pass user ID at compile time as an argument, like:

```
lualatex test.tex 2399
```

This would be for user with `id_user = 2399`. So the problem here is that I have to pass values to lualatex and not lua itself! How can this be done? Can anyone provide a MWE?

Comment: Maybe something similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1495/89417?

Comment: Followed by, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198628/how-to-pass-the-content-of-the-tex-variable-to-lua

Comment: You're supposed to provide the MWE, so that people can modify it to solve the problem. People aren't supposed to need to guess what might or might not be in your code. It isn't clear to me what is where. What triggers the lua script? How can that be read first when you just do `lualatex doc.tex`. Surely, the `.tex` file processing must begin first?

Comment: I would not have marked this as a duplicate. The top-ranked answers on that other page don't specifically deal with LuaTeX, and their proposed solutions are quite different from this one. The LuaTeX-specific answer is found well down the page - obviously so far down that OP did not find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recycled with minor changes from Sharpie's answer to a similar question [Passing parameters to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document)

Within your lua code, the command line arguments are available in `arg`. Here, we just print the arguments, but the code does show how do get hold of them.

```
%argtest.tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent Command line arguments: 

  \directlua{
    if arg then
      for i,v in ipairs(arg) do
        if (i > 1) then
            tex.print("\string\\begin{description}")           
            tex.print("\string\\item[" .. i .. "]" .. v)
            tex.print("\string\\end{description}")           
        end
      end
    end
  }

\end{document}
```

Invoked with

```
lualatex argtest.tex ham spam jam
```

you obtain

[image]

Comment: You can say `if not arg then` (`nil` evaluates to `false` in this context) and please use `ipairs` to iterate in ascending order (`pairs` may iterate in any order, usually order of insertion).

Comment: @HenriMenke - thanks, updated. (The test is `if arg`, and it does work.)